# Spring @PreAuthorize not working in RestController

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security

I have GrantedAuthorities  as `[admin, player, user]` 
To test this I have injected Authentication object in method and invoked   `authentication.getAuthorities().`
but when at REST Controller Method I put `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_player')")`I am getting response for my REST web service as `403 forbidden.`

I have custom roles defined which I am picking from database. I want to authorize REST call before execution of any business logic.
Tried with `@Secured` but still not working.

Comment: They are  admin, player, user from database. I have tried with @PreAuthorize("hasRole('player')") but still not working

Comment: Spring expects roles to be prefixed with ROLE_.   You can either update your roles in your database to ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_PLAYER, ROLE_USER or you should be able to use hasAuthority('admin') instead of hasRole() @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('admin')")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default prefix for hasRole is ROLE_.  If a prefix isn't supplied, spring will automatically add it.  Since your roles in your database aren't prefixed with ROLE_ they will not match with hasRole.

```
// will be checking for ROLE_admin, your role in DB is admin
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('admin')")
```

You can update your roles in your db to prefix them with ROLE_ or you can alter the prefix spring uses on DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.  You should also be able to use hasAuthority rather than hasRole.  The hasAuthority will not add any prefix to the supplied parameter.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('admin')")
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/el-access.html